# Background Task that is triggered on dates compared to initial upload C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-task

I want to implement a background task that is triggered at certain times that are compared to initial upload.

For example, 
the user uploads the data from a WP8 app. A push notification containing that data will be sent to the app 1 day later, then 2 days later, then a week later, then a month later, then six months later. I'm wondering if this is possible with this task or if there is a preferred way of doing this. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you have a push background task than your application is fully clocked by your server.
So it's your server who decides when to send push notification. It has nothing to do with your application. Just send initial installation date to the server together with push url.

On server you may want to use Quartz for scheduling.

If you want to do something periodically within your application than use [TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx)

Comment: I have a WCF service connected to an SQL Server database. So it is possible to time when it is triggered compared to initial upload, I'd just have to do it in my WCF service?

Comment: Yes, your server just need to record the first installation time for each client. You can use Quartz scheduler for scheduling push notifications.